# How to reference View Controller objects from it's category?

Tags: uiviewcontroller, ios8.1, objective-c-category

I have a iPad app for which I created a category for one of the View Controllers; how can I access some labels on a Storyboard *scene* for that View Controller from the category?

This is the code from the category:

```
    if( ([highValue compare: zero] == NSOrderedDescending) && ([lowValue compare: nines] == NSOrderedAscending) &&
   ([computedAverageValue compare:zero] == NSOrderedDescending))  {  //  if there are NO new books, don't display anything
    oHighPriceNew.text = [formatter stringFromNumber: highValue];
    oLowPriceNew.text = [formatter stringFromNumber: lowValue];
    oAveragePriceNew.text = [formatter stringFromNumber: computedAverageValue];
}
```

This is the error for all three labels:

> Use of undeclared identifier 'oHighPriceNew'

They are declared and connected in the View Controller...

[image]

Comment: Do you have outlets defined for these labels in the original View Controller?

Comment: Where have you declared the variables? Add that code also

Comment: Question updated with image of declarations...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to refer the properties either with

```
self.oHighPriceNew.text = [formatter stringFromNumber: highValue];
self.oLowPriceNew.text = [formatter stringFromNumber: lowValue];
self.oAveragePriceNew.text = [formatter stringFromNumber:computedAverageValue];
```

or

```
_oHighPriceNew.text = [formatter stringFromNumber: highValue];
_oLowPriceNew.text = [formatter stringFromNumber: lowValue];
_oAveragePriceNew.text = [formatter stringFromNumber:computedAverageValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

I wound up passing all 6 of the parameters to the called method in the category; works fine.  @Shanti K thank you for your time.  I appreciate it.  SD